# OutputStream Instrumentation: Read byte Array from write Method

Tags: java, outputstream, instrumentation, agent, javassist

For a monitoring project I try to instrument the `OutputStream` class with Javassist. I would like to make the `OutputStream` `write()` method print whatever `byte[]` is given to it (encoding is a different problem and does not matter here). My problem is that replacing the `OutputStream` class during runtime with an agent crashes the JVM. Using Javassist to just manipulate the Bytecode fails as somehow Javassist `ClassPool.get("java.io.OutputStream")` also crashes the JVM.

Is that class so untouchable? The same approach worked fine for the `URI` class.

Is there another way of doing what I would like or is my only option to replace the rt.jar in the JRE?

```
@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer) {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            CtClass cc = pool.get("java.io.OutputStream");
            CtMethod method =
                    Arrays.stream(cc.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(ctMethod -> ctMethod.getLongName().equals("java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[],int,int)"))
                            .findFirst().get();
            method.insertBefore("System.out.println(new String($1, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));");
            return cc.toBytecode();
        } catch (NotFoundException | CannotCompileException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

produces the output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication (wrong name: java/io/OutputStream)

because I overwrite the very first loaded class with my "new" `OutputStream` already. The `OutputStream` class however is never called into the transform method...

Comment: Why not do this in normal Java code as a wrapper class rather than modifying the (many) `OutputStream` implementations?  (That may be the issue: `OutputStream` isn't the class you need to modify; you need to modify all of its subclasses.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman with all subclasses I run into the same issue - some arent piped through the transform methods. My goal is to log EVERY byte written via an OutputStream. If I build a new implementation I can only log the contents going through that one :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transform` method is a callback function that may get invoked for every loaded class. You receive the class name in the `className` parameter and the original definition in the `classfileBuffer`.

So the first thing you have to do, is to check whether current invocation really corresponds to a class you want to transform. If not, just return `null`. You don’t do this, but return a transformed version of `java.io.OutputStream` regardless of which class you were requested to transform. That’s why you get the error. You were requested to transform the class `org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication` but return a class named `java/io/OutputStream`. Note the “wrong name” in the message. Of course, this mismatching class would cause even more problems without that name verification.

After checking that the current invocation is responsible for `java.io.OutputStream`, you should use the provided `classfileBuffer` for reading the original class version, instead of using `ClassPool.getDefault().get(…)`, as the `ClassPool` does not know the version of the class you received in the parameter and might find a wrong version of it or be unable to access the class al all.

But note that instrumenting the method [`OutputStream.write(byte[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) alone is unlikely to be sufficient. As [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) says:

> Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and provide a more efficient implementation.

This happens in practice in all relevant implementation classes. To record the invocations of the overriding methods you have to instrument them as well. Also mind that subclasses may override `write(byte[])` with an implementation that does not delegate to `write(byte[],int,int)`.

Comment: This is a great catch! When I first glanced at the source code I missed the fact that there is no class name check but each class gets transformed to the same target class. 

Comment: I caught on my stupidity of overwriting every class, but still had the issue that OutputStream apparently cannot  be overwritten because it is needed to overwrite itself... It would break in various ways. Your pointing to the implementing methods was a great help, I have now instrumented the write()-methods of the Classes implementing OutputStream which works great.